# Where do I ask the following question

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I posted this question os stackoverflow and im getting hammered. So where shoudl i ask it?

here's the questions:

> Yesterday i got caught in a performance by language argument caused by
>   the fact that Microsoft asked for Java and C++ experience in an job
>   offer.   One party was arguing that Microsoft was not hiring C# devs
>   because internal Microsoft products were not implemented using this
>   "high level language"... that C++ was still a dominant language in all
>   products because of its performance...   So my question is very
>   simple: Which products Microsoft actually implemented using C# on more
>   than 95% of the critical áreas of the code base? (areas where
>   performance is critical for example)

Comment: You seem to be missing a word or two in the question at the end.  Also, "areas" does not require an accent.

Comment: @BenBarden sorry... pt-br auto correct...

Answer (score 12):

Nowhere.  This question is not appropriate for any of the Stack Exchange sites.  There are a few reasons for this:

- It is essentially a  'List of X' question. How do you determine what the right answer is when every answer is equally valid?
- It's not really useful knowledge. It's interesting, but not useful.
- Short of Raymond Chen or someone else at Microsoft answering your question, there's no way to authoritatively get an answer to it -- necessarily this makes it a bit localized.

Answer (score 6):

This question does not belong on any of the Stack Exchange sites.  It is asking for a list of things, and list questions are not appropriate on this network.

(This doesn't mean that they're bad questions, simply that the design of the site isn't capable of properly supporting a large number of answers, of which all of them are a part of the one true "correct" answer.  It's also quite localized, which is something preventing it from being a good fit for the site.)